# Integrate Asp.net MVC (.net framework 4.7) with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, create-react-app, vite

The existing project is MVC with ExtJS. We want to migrate ExtJs to ReactJs alone instead of entire project.

I want to create react-app with existing Asp.net MVC.
I have tried to create using create-react-app or Vite.
But the idea to run Asp.net mvc with ReactJs is,

1. Build react app (will watch build folder)
2. The build output should target _layout.cshtml instead of index.html.
   So that the built files will be included in _layout.cshtml and when we run the mvc application, the app will run without any issues.

Is there any idea to build without index.html and target _layout.cshtml?

Or

Is there any alter idea other than this?

Comment: Why combine MVC and React? Now you've got two different view paradigms - makes everything more complex. Why not have your React app communicate to ASP.NET Web API (preferably on ASP.NET Core)?

Comment: Yes you are right. But as I mentioned earlier, This is existing project. Existing project developed with ExtJS (with asp.net mvc) which is currently paid. So we are migrating only JS Framework. Not the entire project.